# Output pings with time greater than 100ms to file with a timestamp appended

Tags: io-redirection, ping

I want to save in a file every ping with a time greater than 100ms and append a timestamp to every line.

Searching I have managed to get this:

```
ping HOST | grep --line-buffered "time=[0-9][0-9][0-9]" | perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_' > outputFile
```

First I had problems with the buffer of grep, solved with `--line-buffered`. I guess something similar is happening with perl because I get an output in the shell, but nothing in the outputFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`perl` buffers output by default unless you tell it not to by setting `$|` aka `$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH` to a non-zero value.  See `man perlvar` and search for AUTOFLUSH for details.

Also, if you're using perl, you don't need grep as well.

try something like this:

```
ping HOST | perl -nle 'BEGIN { $|=1 } ;
    if (/time=\d\d\d/) { print scalar(localtime), " ", $_}' > outputFile
```

---

BTW, you could also rewrite the script so that instead of piping the output of ping into perl, perl opens a pipe from ping and loops over the input from that.  For example:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl 

# turn off output buffering
$|=1;

# get hostname to ping from command line or use default-hostname
$host=shift || 'default-hostname';

open(IN,'-|',"ping $host") || die "couldn't open pipe from ping: $!\n";
while(<IN>) {
  if (/time=\d\d\d/) { print scalar(localtime), " ", $_ };
};
close(IN);
```

Comment: I actually have no idea about perl. I found that part and just used it. It works like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without perl:

```
ping -c 10 -D HOST | grep -E "time=[1-9][0-9]{2,}" >> output.txt
```

Comment: I like not using perl, but I prefer the human readable timestamp.